# Android -- Multiple activities, keeping them alive, and saving state?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, android-activity

I have an app that creates multiple activities as it traverses a file system (one activity per folder or file, a search activity, etc.). This app sometimes crashes when going [back]. The trace logs indicate that it's crashing in onCreate(...) which tells me that the activities have been destroyed and they are being recreated when going back. This is a problem because I pass data via an Intent when moving forward in the activity stack (i.e. normal folder traversal).

Here is what I get:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(978): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Folder.onCreate(Folder.java:155)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(978):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(978):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)...

What is the best way to deal with memory, multiple (maybe even 0-100?) activities, going back, etc. in an app that functions like a file system browser?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'd like to continue using activities if at all possible, or find a way of preserving the look and feel of moving from one activity to another. It would be ideal if I could get some advice on how to minimize the number of activities (e.g. a method for saving data, closing off-screen activities, yet preserving the [back] animation even if the activity being re-called needs to be recreated). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a new activity for every directory traversal, you are wasting a TON of resources. Instead have one activity that functions as the file browser and just keep your own state (the current fully qualified path) then when the user hits the back button override the default action. See [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

When your `onBackPressed` method is triggered you can take your state (full path) and simply move a directory level.

Simple, efficient and clean.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the app I have is a bit more complicated in that, directory info is loaded from a cloud-based service, files need to be opened/displayed, users need to be able to search for files etc. The app does all this now, but each action is its own activity and activities pass each other data.... thus, the null pointer when one gets closed. Can I use a viewflipper or something similar while maintaining the activity-to-activity animation,etc.? Thanks.

Comment: I still would avoid using that many activities. You can break your app into three components, a directory browser, file viewer and search. Each component only ever needs one instance and you can achieve this with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` set in the Intents.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I want to preserve the activity transition animations, so I'll continue to use activities. Even with many open activities, I've never seen the app use more than 14MB of RAM, and I SoftReference all the bitmaps/drawables used, so I don't get out of memory errors.